# Cypher: iterate and add relationships in subgraph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes with label A and nodes with label B. Each node A has some nodes Bs connected to them `(a)-[:c1]-(b)`.

I want to run a Cypher query to add connections between all nodes B, which are connected to the same node A. Something like

```
match (a:A)<-[:c1]-(b:B)
with collect (b) as bbs
foreach(b in bbs | merge (b1)-[:c2]-(b2) )
```

but I did not found a proper query, yet. I tried the keywords `foreach()`, `unwind`, `apoc.path.subgraphAll()`, `relationships()`, `startNode()` and so on.

Comment: You have not indicated why you want to add those extra relationships. But in general one should carefully consider whether adding redundant data (like relationships that just summarize existing relationships) is worth the extra coding, storage, and execution costs. Remember, once you add those new relationships, you will have to add code to keep them in sync with the relationships that they summarize, and vice versa. You should only do this kind of thing if you have a use case that justifies the increased complexity and resource usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need these functions for this task.

You can do it simply with the following query:

```
MATCH (thisB:B)-[:c1]->(a:A)<-[:c1]-(otherB:B)
MERGE (thisB)-[:c2]-(otherBs)
```